# How to execute a folder (vpk.exe) with cmd

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have a vpk.exe application which if i drag a folder onto the vpk.exe the folder gets nameOfFolder.vpk file. Its for game moding.
How can i do this with batch. Batch drag and drop onto the vpk.exe.

Answer (score 2):

When you drag and drop a file or folder onto a batch file or executable, Windows launches the drop target and passes the full name of the dropped object as a command-line argument, with quotes if necessary.

It appears that your program takes a folder name on the command line, so the equivalent command would be `vpk "C:\Full\Path\To\Folder"`. You might be able to get away with relative paths, so `vpk Folder` could work if you're in the directory containing `vpk` and `Folder`. Note that `vpk` can be anywhere if it's on your `PATH`.